# Search From Plist

Tags: ios, plist

Can some help me to this

I loaded `plist`  when app startup my app and I have a search input. When I insert text to input I want to search from `plist`

```
self.plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xutbe"] ofType:@"plist"];
self.allData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:self.plistFile];
```

I tryed like this but not work

```
NSString *INPUT = @"s";
self.plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"filename"] ofType:@"plist"];
self.allData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:self.plistFile];

NSArray *searchRes = [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", INPUT]];
NSLog(@"%@", searchRes);
```

And also tried this and not work

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xutbe" ofType:@"plist"]; NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]; NSDictionary* vcDict = [dict valueForKey:@"sd"]; NSLog(@"%@", vcDict);
```

Comment: You should probably be more specific about the contents of the plist. Is it an array of strings? or an array of dictionaries?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to search an object from NSArray use **NSPredicate**

```
NSArray *searchRes = [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate
   predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", INPUT]];
```

Comment: `CONTAINS` or `BEGINSWITH` might be better keywords than `==`

Comment: This will lead to decent results if the array contains strings

Answer (score 2):

You should try the following to search for the input string at the beginning of the string:

```
NSPredicate *pred  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH %@", INPUT];
NSArray *searchRes = [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

or to search for the string anywhere:

```
NSPredicate *pred  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS %@", INPUT];
NSArray *searchRes = [self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

You might want to have a look at the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/predicates/Articles/pUsing.html